# Count percentage of certain column values and add it to a new column

Tags: sql, select, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a following table

```
[Table_OrangeIsNewBlack]
ID  |   Name    |   Color   |   RedPercent
------------------------------------------
1   |   Donald  |   Orange  |   
2   |   Hillary |   White   |   
3   |   Barack  |   Black   |   
4   |   Bernie  |   Grey    |   
1   |   Donald  |   Red     |   
2   |   Hillary |   Red     |   
3   |   Barack  |   Black   |   
4   |   Bernie  |   Grey    |   
1   |   Donald  |   Red     |   
2   |   Hillary |   Blue    |   
3   |   Barack  |   Red     |   
4   |   Bernie  |   Purple  |
```

I need to add a percentage value presenting how often person is 'Red'

---

Donald's record

```
1       Donald      Orange      
1       Donald      Red         
1       Donald      Red
```

RedPercent : (2 / 3 ) * 100 = 66,66

---

Hillary

```
2       Hillary     White       
2       Hillary     Red         
2       Hillary     Blue
```

'Blue' and 'Purple' do not count, thus :

RedPercent  :       (1 / 2) * 100 = 50,00

---

Barack

```
3       Barack      Black       
3       Barack      Black       
3       Barack      Red
```

RedPercent  :       (1 / 3) * 100 = 33,33

---

Bernie

```
4       Bernie      Grey        
4       Bernie      Blue        
4       Bernie      Purple
```

'Blue' and 'Purple' do not count

RedPercent  :       (0 / 1) * 100 = 00,00

Result needed:

```
[Table_OrangeIsNewBlack]
ID  |   Name    |   Color   |   RedPercent
------------------------------------------
1   |   Donald  |   Orange  |   66,66
2   |   Hillary |   White   |   50,00
3   |   Barack  |   Black   |   33,33
4   |   Bernie  |   Grey    |   00,00
1   |   Donald  |   Red     |   66,66
2   |   Hillary |   Red     |   50,00
3   |   Barack  |   Black   |   33,33
4   |   Bernie  |   Grey    |   00,00
1   |   Donald  |   Red     |   66,66
2   |   Hillary |   Blue    |   50,00
3   |   Barack  |   Red     |   33,33
4   |   Bernie  |   Purple  |   00,00
```

I've tried :

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  ID, 
                    -- Division: count of Reds  / count of persons all rows 
                    ((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
                    WHERE Color = 'Red' )
                    /       
                    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
                    WHERE ( Color  <> 'Blue' and
                            Color  <> 'Purple' ))
                    )
                    AS redprcnt
                -- end of Division
        FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
    )
    UPDATE T1
        SET RedPercent = CTE.redprcnt
        FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack T1 
    INNER JOIN CTE ON(T1.ID = CTE.ID)
```

SELECT clause...

```
SELECT  ID, 
            -- Division: count of Reds  / count of persons all rows 
            ((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
            WHERE Color = 'Red' )
            /       
            (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
            WHERE ( Color  <> 'Blue' and
                    Color  <> 'Purple' ))
            )
            AS redprcnt
        -- end of Division
FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
```

...gives only zeros for redprcnt

Should i use GROUP BY at some point?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` usually results in a INTEGER, thus `COUNT/COUNT` is an integer division which truncates and your base query tries to calculate the overall percentage instead of the % per group.

Additionally your calculation can be simplified using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT ID,
        -- Division: count of Reds  / count of persons all rows 
   100.00 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN ID END)
          / NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN Color  <> 'Blue' and Color  <> 'Purple'  THEN ID END), 0) AS redprcnt
FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
GROUP BY ID
```

The `CASE` returns NULL for non-matching rows which are not counted.

Edit:

If you actually need to repeat the percentage for each row you can switch to a *Windowed Aggregate* instead:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Color, 
   100.00 * Count(CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN ID END) Over(PARTITION BY NAME)
          / NULLIF(Count(CASE WHEN Color  <> 'Blue' AND Color  <> 'Purple'  THEN ID END) Over(PARTITION BY NAME), 0) AS redprcnt
 FROM Table_OrangeIsNewBlack
```

Comment: Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.    How to avoid divide by 0 ?

Comment: `NULLIF` requires 2 argumetnts. Made a correction:  `THEN ID END), 0) AS redprcnt`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Task, I have made script that may help you

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT * ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN ID END) OVER(Partition by Name,Color) ColorCount,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN Color  <> 'Blue' and Color  <> 'Purple'  THEN ID END)  OVER(Partition by Name)TotalCount
  FROM TableName
)
SELECT ID,Name, (SELECT MAX(((ColorCount*1.0)/(CASE WHEN TotalCount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE TotalCount END))*100) 
                 FROM CTE InnerCte 
                 WHERE OuterCTE.ID=InnerCte.ID AND OuterCTE.Name=InnerCte.Name )
FROM CTE OuterCTE
```

Comment: Divide by zero error encountered. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. How to avoid divide by 0 ?

Comment: COUNT OVER suppress the functionality of GROUP BY if we use simple COUNT then we need it to GROUP BY ID and Name  and this will not produce result what op is looking for

Comment: Edited `SELECT ID,Name, (SELECT MAX((COALESCE( (ColorCount*1.0) /NULLIF(ColorCount,0) ,0)*100))`